# Golang print "nil"

Tags: go

i am reading the golang tutorial: https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/10
And i am confused about how `fmt.Println` prints the `nil` value, hope you could help me out.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    var z []int
    fmt.Println("z: ", z)
    if z == nil {
        fmt.Println("z is nil!")
    } 
    fmt.Println("nil:", nil)
}
```

the result is:

```
z:  []
z is nil!
nil: <nil>
```

Since z is a nil, why is z printed as `[]` but not `<nil>`?

thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `fmt` package uses reflection to determine what to print. Since the type of `z` is a slice, `fmt` uses the `[]` notation.

Since slices, channels, interfaces and pointers can all be nil, it helpful if `fmt` prints something different when it can. If you want more context, use the `%v` format: http://play.golang.org/p/I1SAVzlv9f

```
var a []int
var b chan int
var c *int
var e error
fmt.Printf("a:%#v\n", a)
fmt.Printf("b:%#v\n", b)
fmt.Printf("c:%#v\n", c)
fmt.Printf("e:%#v\n", e)
```

Prints:

```
a:[]int(nil)
b:(chan int)(nil)
c:(*int)(nil)
e:<nil>
```

Answer (score -2):

The word nil means : not initialized.
In this case you are initializing  the slide but no values have bean assigned yet.
Remember PICS (Pointers, Interfaces, CHANNELS , and SLIDES )are all already
initialized.